# Jenkins transferring 0 files using publish over SSH plugin

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to transfer files from my post build Jenkins workspace to a location on a remote server. Build goes smoothly for all steps in the job but always transfers 0 files.

This is the console output:

```
    Started by user Patrick
    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/20eyes Build/workspace
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
    Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/project/project.git
    using .gitcredentials to set credentials
    Checking out Revision a758e0f8e534271b999a2fc8696b6fd5a3d5e500 (origin/master)
    executing script:

    cd /var/www/20eyes-web
    [SSH] exit-status: 0
    SSH: Connecting from host [dev1.remotehost]
    SSH: Connecting with configuration [dev2.remotehost] ...
    SSH: Disconnecting configuration [dev2.remotehost] ...
    SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
    Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to  SUCCESS
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

The job is configured to build after any commit is pushed to GitHub

The transfer set is:
Source Files:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/20eyes Build/workspace/**/*
```

Remove prefix:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/20eyes Build/workspace
```

Comment: go there you will find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842747/8327498

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I thinks, problem at your config.
We have 2 positions to configure.

1. At System configuration (Global config).

   --> If test ok ==> Configuration to remote server is ok.
2. At your project.
   We will focus about transfer set: (Source file, Remove prefix, remote directory)

   2.1 Source file : if it's blank = workspace directory.
      in your case i think you should input `**/*`
   2.2 Remove prefix : refer [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-transfer)  for more info.
   2.3 Remote directory: if it's blank = directory that is configured at System configuration above.

Hope it help!
Sorry about my English.

Comment: This took care of it, in particular 2.1. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to copy files which are not in my workspace (from /var/www/<mysite> to destination VM), but I always get `SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)`
I tried many variants of `/var/www/mysite` for the source file, prefixing with \*\*/, or suffixing with /\*, /\*\* or /\*/\*\*... nothing seems to work. 
What m I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Balmipour Have you found a way to get to the parent directory of your current job workspace?

Comment: @Bruno I just created a symlink in the project, which somehow "fixed" the issue, but is hacky & dirty.  Note that renaming the project would change the directory used by Jenkins to a new one, which won't contain the link.  I'd love a better solution :)

Comment: @Balmipour ok thank you symlink would in fact work. Yes, it's hacky and not a smooth solution. I think the plugins use case is another one then we intend it to use.

Comment: I have a file in workspace folder named `hello-world.tar.gz`
My server connection is good.
getting SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
how do i solve this problem?

Comment: I see this answer is quite old but it helped solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: For me works with *.zip But doesn't work with specific file.

Answer (score 10):

Quick thing to try first: set the Source folder only with: **/* to see if any file is copied. If file was copied then take a look here to see how to write the correct path [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

Answer (score 5):

My advices:

1. **You should avoid using spaces in the Jenkins job name!**

   - in your case: name `20eyes Build` can produce some troubles in file/directory matching
2. **You should use relative paths and not absolute paths!**

   - in your case: `/var/lib/jenkins/...` should be replaced by relative path from job's workspace
3. **You should NOT copy whole workspace!**

   - specify only appropriate files from last build (e.g. WAR file from target directory)
4. **You should check documentation and examples of [Publish Over plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over)**:

   - [examples](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-Examples) will be very usefull for You

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Definitely going to fix my jobs to reflect your advice

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the absolute path(from root) in "Transfer Set Source Files:". When I changed the path relative to the workspace, It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another common mistake with `sourceFiles`

This will NOT work:

- `sourceFiles: '/path/dir/**'`
- `sourceFiles: '../dir/**'`
- and even `sourceFiles: './dir/**'` !

While this WILL:

- `sourceFiles: 'dir/**'`

Behaviour explained [in plugin docs:](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/) `sourceFiles` is a  string, comma separated list of includes for an **Ant fileset** eg. '**/*.jar' (see Patterns in the Ant manual).

Whereas patterns in the Ant manual say:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns

> In general, patterns are considered relative paths, **relative** to a task dependent base directory (the dir attribute in the case of ). **Only** files found below that base directory are considered. So while a pattern like ../foo.java is possible, **it will not match anything** when applied since the **base directory's parent is never scanned** for files.

Answer (score 0):

```
After Appropriated configuring the SSH server/host in:
```

> Manage Jenkins >> configure System >> SSH Server

```
Then you can configure the source file in this format **/*.war or **/*.jar as the case may be.


The remote directory in this format: //opt//copyfolder
```

Refer the image below for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You guys missed the simple thing:

**Make sure your path doesn't start with "/"**

Comment: This is already covered by some answers, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32815720/735926) from 2015.