# Jenkins, SSH plugin, 0 files transferred

Tags: ssh, jenkins

We are a group of three doing a project using MEANJS, Bitbucket is our source control and we are using Jenkins for test automation and CI. We want to use Jenkins to pull from Bitbucket, build and run tests and then deploy the project via SSH to another machine.

We have a connection between Bitbucket and Jenkins, Jenkins is hosted on a windows server, after that we want to deploy our project via SSH and we are able to connect to our CentOS server using SSH, the connection is a success but the transfer always has 0 files:

```
Started by user Centris
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Evert
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url     https://evertJenkins:teamEvert@bitbucket.org/evert-team/evert.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://evertJenkins@bitbucket.org/evert-team/evert.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10 using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\centris\AppData\Local\Temp\git2236090933781388612.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://evertJenkins@bitbucket.org/evert-team/evert.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b0ca93376cb8b1799a069a7e33e212ebc886261a (origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f b0ca93376cb8b1799a069a7e33e212ebc886261a
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-list b0ca93376cb8b1799a069a7e33e212ebc886261a # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #39 jenkins-Evert-39 #     timeout=10
SSH: Connecting from host [centris]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Centris leit] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Centris leit] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to SUCCESS
SSH: Connecting from host [centris]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Centris leit] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Centris leit] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Our project is named Evert and thus it is located under workspace\Evert.

We have tried all forms of strings for our source files, from a full path down to what we have now that is:

```
Evert\**\*
```

We also have remove prefix set as:

```
Evert\
```

we have tried following this: [Jenkins transferring 0 files using publish over SSH plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158092/jenkins-transferring-0-files-using-publish-over-ssh-plugin) but we still have the same problem. Can anyone please tell us what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply archive it and scp the archive to the CentOS machine. Not all Jenkins plugins are created equal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found 2 issues:

1. the files in the transfer set are relative to the job workspace. So you just use `**`
2. setting a destination directory in the SSH server setup and on the SSH server in the build configuration causes it to double the path (i.e. `/tmp` in both places results in `/tmp/tmp`)