# Jenkins not copying folder structure of project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to deploy with Jenkins. I'm sending to a server, and the folder `www` receives the files from the root project, but doesn't receive any of the folders and subfolders. How can I fix this?

I thought it could be permissions, so I tried to give chmod 777 to www, but didn't work anyway.

I have configured my server (hostname, username, and remote directory). Then I create my job with a git config (url, credentials, and branch to watch), job will run every minute. In the Build option, I put source files (*), Exec Command (commands for migrations and things like that). When it runs, my `www` folder was empty and receives files, but not folders.

Comment: There are a lot of unanswered questions here.  We have no idea how you are "deploying". Without more information, you will not likely get many useful answers.

Comment: I have configured my server (hostname, username, and remote direcory). Then I create my job with a git config (url, credential, and branch to watch), job will run every minute). In the Build option I put souce files (*), Exec Comand (comands for migrations and things like that). Just it It runs, my www was empty and receive files but not folders

Comment: Please [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice); it's the rule.

Comment: Ok but when I try to help someone commenting on their question I need reputation, I don't have enought reputation. And when I ask something someone goes and mark as bad question making my reputation down. How can I grow this way? very upsed about it

Comment: @AndréGava I can sympathize; we've all received downvotes with no explanation before. Still doesn't give us an excuse to curse out at folks on here. I don't know who downvoted your question or why. I can only recommend that you make sure your post follows the recommendations listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the help, pacience and tips. I'll try to make better questions now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this link that explain how to do a best configuration for Jenkins:  [Jenkins transferring 0 files using publish over SSH plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158092/jenkins-transferring-0-files-using-publish-over-ssh-plugin) and I've discover why Jenkins just send files and not folders, this * should be **/* in Source files.